# How to modified an existing Android app to autorun every x minutes manually with apktool?

Tags: android, apktool

How can I modified an existing android application with apktool so it can autorun every x minutes or autorun after boot or autorun when wifi connects? .I have search and found that I must register a broadcast receiver but I can't do it manually when decompiled with apktool.

Answer (score 0):

That's not good practice: you should not do anything with already zipped apk. Get the source code and modify it.

Or write your own application with this function :) GL!

Comment: i have the source code but i dont know how to add a broadcast receiver.shall i add the code in a file bootreceiver.jar i need one example.thanks for your answerd